# Как записываются функции в памяти?

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

Мне известно, что функция это набор обычных инструкций/команд и т. д. При чем адресом этой функции является адрес на её первую инструкцию. Так вот меня интересует вопрос, как этот самый адрес определяется, если в машинном коде (насколько мне известно) нет никаких имен (для локальных переменных используется структура, описывающая эту переменную, а для глобальных смещение задано уже с момента компиляции). P. s. пишу на с++, вдруг есть какие то различия с другими языками

Comment: Возьмите книжку-другую по ассемблеру, мне кажется, это основательно вам поможет. Но если вас интересует работа именно на ЯВУ - то это не то, что должно вас беспокоить... А так, попросту - инструкция находится в памяти? В памяти. Эта ячейка памяти имеет адрес? Имеет. Ну и все, что вам еще нужно? :)

Comment: @Harry, в том то и дело, что не на ЯВУ, мне очень нравится с++ поэтому хочу знать как можно больше) Меня интересует, как именно моя программа получает адрес этой инструкции, он же не определяется во время компиляции, как например  со статическими переменными.

Comment: Возможно я не совсем понятно объясняю, сейчас подумаю как получше сформулировать)

Comment: `как именно моя программа получает адрес этой инструкции, он же не определяется во время компиляции` - адрес становится известен в момент компиляции. Грубо говоря, при компиляции имена функций заменяются на адреса.

Comment: @insolor, благодарю, я думал это по другому работает)

Comment: Тут еще много зависит от режима работы процессора, от операционки... Например, в DOS в `.exe` хранилась т.н. relocation table, по которой после размещения образа в памяти в нужных местах операционка прописывала прямо в коде в памяти конкретные физические адреса...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В момент запуска программы, её код загружается в операционную систему. Ответ поверхностный. Не буду вдаваться в детали, там можно очень легко запутаться. Чтобы хорошо понять эту тему действительно нужно разбираться в ассемблере.

В ассемблере есть так называемые `label`, метки которые указывают на первую инструкцию. Рассмотрим простейший вариант, программа загружена в оперативную память:

```
start: ; Метка, по сути точка входа исполнения программы, будем считать что её адрес в памяти 0x55
  # некоторый исполняемый код
  mov ...
  call func
  push ...
  pop ...
  mov ax, 4c00h ; Возврат управления ОС
  int 21h
func: ; Метка функции
  mov ...
  ret ; Благодаря call, мы сохранили адрес вызова в стеке, возвращаемся
```

Метка функции является именованной константой, но за ней также скрывается адрес. Как видим выше метки, есть некоторый исполняемый код, он также хранится в памяти, каждая инструкция занимает место, так что метка `func` будет находится по адресу `start + (сумма адресов всех предыдущих команд)`. Для простоты вычислений будем считать, что каждая команда занимается единицу адреса, тогда метка будет находится по адресу `5B`. В действительности, метка скрывает только относительную величину (сколько нужно прибавить к адресу начала программы, чтобы получить адрес метки, т.е. по факту там будет храниться `6`).

С помощью linker можно соединять объявления нескольких скомпилированных программ. Однако это снова довольно обширная тема для обсуждения, лучше почитать.

P.S. Ответ поверхностный, если данный ответ вас не удовлетворяет напишите в комментарии, я удалю.